# How to use maxmind geoiplite2 mmdb file on ubuntu server

Tags: amazon-web-services, geolocation, ubuntu-16.04, maxmind

Currently, I am using Maxmind geolitecity for converting IP to location. Maxmind recently announced they are no longer supporting geolite (.dat format)

**How to install Geolite2city mmdb on ubuntu server?**

**How to convert mmdb file to dat format?**

Comment: There is no need to convert. You will need to port your codes to support the new mmdb file.

Comment: @MichaelC What all changes need to make on server to support mmdb format